# Movie about an older couple traveling in a Time Machine that is in a tomb—theirs, and the boy who follows them and gets lost

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I saw this movie recently but I don’t know the name. It starts with an older couple interviewing a boy to work for them. They give him their house and money while they’re gone. They have experimented with a banana in a box, I think for a week, but it’s fresh; then they each get into a box and tell the boy to open them in a week. They are aware of no time passing, to them he just closed the lids. Finally, they go into a tomb that hides their time machine. The boy follows them in later and (of course) gets into trouble.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see it?  Was it live-action or animated?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters?

Comment: It was live action. I thought it was on Amazon prime, but I couldn’t find in when I wanted to show someone else. My husband thinks it might have been British. I don’t remember any names, sorry.

Comment: Did it look like recent movie or one from several decades ago?

Comment: Hard to say. I don’t think it was that old.

Answer (score 5):

*[Escape 2120](https://dove.org/review/19506-escape-2120/)* from 2020.

[image: Movie poster for Escape 2120]

> Dave's agreement with Doc and Sally is to help the two adventurous scientists disappear into the future. But being left behind by the closest people Dave has to family isn't the bargain the 18-year-old expected. When Dave follows after his mentors, calibration issues place him centuries past his target date. Countless years and miles of wilderness separate Dave from Doc and Sally. Dave must survive in a primitive new world that has been waiting for him for a very ... long ... time ...

The trailer popped up when searching for `film "suspended animation" banana`

### Trailer

The banana box:
[image: Image of the banana inside one of their gimmicked boxes]

Comment: Heh.  That looks a lot like the potato-powered Stepper from the Long Earth series by Terry Pratchett.

Comment: Thank you! That’s definitely the right movie; and now, with the title, I found it on Tubi. Thanks again. (I think I’m really going to like this web site.)

Comment: @MareCat: I should have mentioned that you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. But I'm glad you found what you were looking for!

Comment: The moment I read the question, I knew this was the movie. Unfortunately I couldn't remember the name of it either. I know I saw it about 4 months ago.